# Cargo fails to download dependencies when running in GitHub Actions

Tags: rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

When `cargo check` runs in a GitHub Action, it downloads most of the dependencies but occasionally fails on one of them. It fails on different ones on each run (I tested it around 5 times).

Downloading dependencies works locally.

```
  Downloaded sys-info v0.5.10
  Downloaded strum_macros v0.19.4
  Downloaded proc-macro-error v1.0.4
  Downloaded pin-utils v0.1.0
  Downloaded v_escape v0.15.0
  Downloaded uuid v0.7.4
  Downloaded typeable v0.1.2
  Downloaded syn v1.0.73
  Downloaded strum v0.20.0
error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/rustc-demangle/0.1.20/download`
Error: failed to download from `https://crates.io/api/v1/crates/rustc-demangle/0.1.20/download`
Caused by:
  [55] Failed sending data to the peer (Connection died, tried 5 times before giving up)
Error: The process '/usr/share/rust/.cargo/bin/cargo' failed with exit code 101
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Sounds like a networking problem - I would consider opening a support ticket with GitHub.

Comment: Is it always the same package that fails to download? Also, has this been happening for awhile? The fact that other packages downloaded and one failed makes me wonder if it was a transient issue or if its that specific URL that's causing a problem.

Comment: @egerhard It's not always the same package that cargo fails to download. This issue appeared yesterday for the first time. When I'm not changing anything in the code and just re-run the action it happens for around 50% of the CI runs.

Comment: Yeah, definitely open a ticket with GitHub.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior with GitLab-CI custom runners in a private EKS cluster using NAT gateways for egress. So this doesn't appear to be limited to a GitHub network issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like it’s a problem with the nightly toolchain.
Changing `toochain: nightly` to `toolchain: nightly-2021-07-05`
in the ci file solved it:

```yaml
uses: actions-rs/toolchain@v1
with:
  profile: minimal
  toolchain: nightly-2021-07-05
  override: true
  components: rustfmt
```

Comment: Version locking my `cargo` commands to `toolchain-2021-07-05` worked for me. GitLab-CI via custom k8s runners in a private EKS w/ NAT gateway. In my case, `cargo +nightly fmt --all --check` intermittently resulted in `Error during execution of cargo metadata: Updating git repository` -- which would fail on seemingly random packages (with the same error cause: `[55]`. I version lock by building a container with `rustup toolchain install nightly-2021-07-05 --component rustfmt --allow-downgrade` and running the `cargo fmt` command as above in a GitLab-CI job. Thanks for the tip!